# Can I use ElectronJS to just make a GUI of my NodeJS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

That's actually my first question here, and I'm in a serious doubt of platform to develop an application for my company.

Here's what a I need to do: Create a Windows App that communicates over TCP/IP with multiple hardwares on a local lan network. The company already has an app that does so, but it was written in Delphi in 2009 and it has several bugs on Windows 10.

I've already written some code for server and client applications on NodeJS (Javascript), but we need a GUI so it's easy to exchange data with all hardwares connected to the local lan.

We've tried some of C# + .NET, but javascript looks nicer nowadays ;)

Is ElectronJS a good idea? Always heard of it but never really jumped into an application with it.

Comment: Hi, Congratulations on your first post. Electron is for building a cross-platform app based on chromium and Node API.

Comment: sure, electron/node can do anything.

Comment: Yes, Electron is basically NodeJS on a browser so you can use it alongside your NodeJS code to build a cross platform app with an UI.